# Conditions for Swapping min and mMax

Tags: reference-request, optimization, maxima-minima

I have a two-step optimization problem now, which is
\begin{equation}
\max_{\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathcal{X}}\min_{\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathcal{Y}}f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}) \;.
\end{equation}
I am curious under which conditions I can switch the order of $\min$ and $\max$ to
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathcal{Y}}\max_{\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathcal{X}}f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}) \;.
\end{equation}
Could anybody please refer me to some literature about this topic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Theorems which provide these conditions are called [minimax theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem). Two useful minimax theorems are Von Neumann's and [Sion's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem).

Sion's theorem, which is more general, requires:

X to be compact and convex

Y to be convex

$f$ to be upper semi-continuous and quasi-concave in $y$ for all $x$

$f$ to be lower semi-continuous and quasi-convex in $x$ for all $y$